# Cómo asignarle nombre a una transacción con SQLServer Compact

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-ce

En SQLServer *normal*, cuando realizas un `BeginTransaction()`, dentro de los paréntesis puedes poner un string para asignarle un nombre a la transacción. En SQLServer Compact no viene esa opción. ¿Alguien sabe cómo hacerlo?

Comment: Que yo sepa, simplemente no es posible. ¿Pudieras explicar la necesidad de hacerlo? Tal vez exista una alternativa aceptable. (Y de paso, ya lo corregí, pero por favor no te olvides la puntuación en tus preguntas. De lo contrario, no es fácil leer cuando todo parece ser una sola frase)

Comment: Gracias ya lo investigue y en efecto no es posible procurare escribir con mejor puntuación en la siguiente gracias!

Comment: Sergio Camilo, puedes incluir una respuesta a tu propia pregunta indicando que no es posible y tal vez indicando qué hiciste en su lugar para futuros interesados

Answer (score 0):

Que tal estuve investigando después de tiempo y lo que descubrí fue que no se podían hacer transacciones en SQL Compact no esta disponible